# React component in another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginner in React, but have to ask this question because I can't find answer

This is my code

```
 class UserLogin extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const {title} = this.props
        return(
            <p> {title} </p>
        );
    }
}

class UserGuide extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <p> Test class </p>,
                <UserLogin title = "Nexicolt" />
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <UserGuide/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Output is

`Nexicolt`

not

```
test class 
Nexicolt
```

Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that a comma after `<p>` is located outside JSX, so it's JavaScript syntax and not HTML text node.

[Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) ignores the first part of an expression, `<p> Test class </p>`, and returns only the second part from render functon, `<UserLogin title = "Nexicolt" />`.

If there are multiple children elements, either an array should be returned:

```
return [
    <p> Test class </p>,
    <UserLogin title = "Nexicolt" />
];
```

Or a fragment:

```
return <>
    <p> Test class </p>
    <UserLogin title = "Nexicolt" />
</>;
```

If you are not sure you have good uses for comma operator, ESLint [`no-sequences`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sequences) rule can be used to prevent it from being used and avoid potential mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React 16.* then you can use fragment:

```
return <>
    <p> Test class </p>
    <UserLogin title = "Nexicolt" />
</>;
```

or return array

```
return [
    <p> Test class </p>,
    <UserLogin title = "Nexicolt" />
];
```

and if you are using React below 16 then wrap it inside div as follows:

```
return (
     <div>
        <p> Test class </p>,
        <UserLogin title = "Nexicolt" />
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having Comma operator in the render function, it will only take the last part of the render function.

```
<p> Test class 1</p>,
<UserLogin title = "Nexicolt" />,
<p> Test class 2</p>
```

This will return the result 'Test class 2'.